Error error: library "librnscreens.so" not found, js engine: hermes
when I try to run : npm run android i got the following error:
**ERROR  Error: Exception in HostObject::get for prop 'RNSModule': java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "librnscreens.so" not found, js engine: hermes**
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes

I change the build.gradle to
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: true, 
    bundleInDebug: true // clean and rebuild if changing
]

reset cache
no success
the App runs fine in ios
Does anyone have an idea ?
I am using Visual Code in Mac with android studio and emulators

I faced the same thing, I guess this is due to very recent changes in react-native-screens.
I solved it by downgrading:
"@react-navigation/native": "6.0.13",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "6.4.0",
"react-native-screens": "3.14.0"

hope it helps.
